# 2001 Manual Mercedes C220 CDI - ECU replacement

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz, electronic-control-module, c220

Well bring a really typical blond I switched the jumper leads onto the wrong terminals on the battery.Red to black and Visa Versa. I blew up the on board computer.

Hence I blew up the ECU. I really love this car.

Now do I replace only the ECU or do I also have to replace the key module inside the car and a silver piece I don’t know what it is called.

Please help I have managed to find exactly the correct ECU’s with the correct Mercedes part no but do I need to replace the other 2 things.

I really would appreciate an URGENT reply from anyone who knows please.

Thanks
Debbie

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If a diyer, did you check every fuse and replace blown ones? The 'smoke test'; observing smoke from connecting jumper cables incorrectly may help point to damaged wiring, burned electronics, etc. Most if not all EFI systems go thru their power on self tests in a recognizable sequence with indicator lights from the instrument panel during startup. If you remember how indicators lit up then turned off, these are clues. The ecu may have a body computer that runs all lights, indicators with OBD II  port. If this overwhelms you, find an auto electrical/electronics specialist.

Comment: I tried all that but they now say a need the car key part and the immobiliser to make the vehicle go again. Then it must be programmed with a computer. 

Thanks for the help though.